# How do I convert a C# tuple into an F# tuple?

Tags: f#

How do I convert a C# tuple into an F# tuple?

Specifically, I have a C# implementation of a Result type:

```
public class Result<T,E>
{
    public Result(T data) => Ok    = (true,data);

    public Result(E data) => Error = (true,data);

    public (bool,T) Ok    { get; }
    public (bool,E) Error { get; }
}
```

I want to take the tuple value of an Ok result or Error result and use it in my F# code.

Example:

```
let result = databaseService.getSomething(userIdValue) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

let isSuccessful,forms = result.Ok
```

However, I receive the following error:

> Error FS0001  One tuple type is a struct tuple, the other is a
>   reference tuple

In conclusion, I am confused on how to convert a C# tuple into an F# tuple.
I found this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjj08eigqrgAhUqnq0KHSayA1IQFjAAegQICxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F17775590%2Fhow-to-convert-between-f-and-c-sharp-tuples&usg=AOvVaw2yJi6lDB8jLxtf2Dc5UTIa). But I wasn't able to leverage it for what I needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# 7.0 tuple syntax produces [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.7.2) values which are different from F# tuples (the older [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) classes).
Luckilly since F# 4.1 you can use

```
let struct (isSuccessful, forms) = result.Ok
```

Notice the extra `struct` keyword in the pattern. You can use the same syntax to create new `ValueTuple` values, like `let tup = struct (true, 42)`